# How to use multiple data types in Diffable datasource?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource

I have a collection view with 4 sections that each section have a different Item type. How should I achieve this with **UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource**?
I tried **AnyHashable** and **enum associated values** but I cant figured it out how should I use it on dataSource implementation (and collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell).

Comment: An enum with associated values is typically how this is done. You will need to show us your code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70254267/9086770